# Let $f(x) = 1 / p(x)$ . What is the degree of the denominator of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)$ (when fully simplified)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $k$.
 Let $f(x) = 1 / p(x)$ . What is the degree of the denominator of $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)$ (when fully simplified)?

An answer was given to me, that being that the degree is $k + n$, and I think it has something to do with the power rule and its relationship with fractions, but I can't come to the answer correctly and could use a little help. I couldn't find any on the google machine or on any existing questions here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try at least with $n = 1$ and $n = 2$. Then, see if you can use induction.

Comment: look at the general $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum_i^k a_ix^i$ and see what you can deduce.

Comment: I guess I should specify that I'm really rough with calculus and I don't think i know what induction is or how to use epsilon here